# Problems with Microsoft Graph API and Python

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

I am not a professional coder, but built some scripts for our small business with Python3.

I regularly ran into problems with the Microsoft Graph API. I am using requests to connect to the REST API. I want to delete an adressbook and create another one with different contacts.
I have no problems with authentication and token generation. Creating the new adressbook and contacts runs also without any trouble.
However, when I try to delete the old adressbook I get errors on a regular basis. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
users_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders/' + FolderID
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(Token)}
DeleteFolder_r = requests.delete(users_url, headers=headers)
```

The 503 error message is something like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-22T01:00:32",
      "request-id": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
      "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

In general the service seems to work, because I get the tokens directly before the error above without any problems. Is there any way to test if the service is up and running before I try to delete the adressbook?

Thanks for your help and support!

Marc

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue. Please give a try in POSTMAN or [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and see if you can still repro the issue. If so, please share the request id and timestamp with the whole error message.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. It runs sometimes without any problems. Sometimes however I get the error message. I tried it in Graph Explorer and it worked quite fine. Is it really possible that the Microsoft Servers are too busy sometimes?

Comment: Could you please share the requestid and timestamp for the failed request?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The requestid is 0966694f-51bd-41f2-9c88-1d21eebfbecc. The timestamp is 2020-11-22T01:00:32

Comment: From the logs I got to know that there is a throttling issue, try implementing the [Retry-After](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling) so that after a delay it will be deleted.